# Running a package from memory with out saving it

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ssis

I created a SSIS package pro-grammatically in C-sharp. Now I am running the package by creating it and saving it as FileName.dtsx and executing it as package.execute();
Now what I want to do is run the package in the memory itself without saving it. Is this possible to do that.
Tried a lot but cannot figure it out how to do that.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that, but it would definitely help if you explain why you want to do it. If you explain that, then someone may have a solution.

Comment: I did not understand either. Could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't save it?

```
    static void Amarnath()
    {
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package p = null;
        p = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package();
        p.Execute();

    }
```

Comment: @Pondlife I already have many flat-files that needs to be processed using SSIS package and for each file I am generating temporary files. So I don't want to increase the file count in the system(This looks weird but that is what required.) 
To explain it, when we create a Package in SSIS(not through a program) we will add it to a project and run it. But when we are creating the package through the program I am just calling package.execute() to run it. But I think that there is no difference between the two methods. So I want to run the program without physically creating the package file.